# jquery find vs context selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container, which gets rows dynamically added to it.
I then have a remove button, which should do 1 of 2 things.

if all rows are empty, then remove all except the first one.
if there are any populated rows, then remove all empty items after the last populated one.

e.g.
Example 1:

Before removal:

- empty
- empty
- empty

After:

- empty

Example 2:

Before removal:

- empty
- populated
- empty
- empty

After:

- empty
- populated

I have this working (see code below).
However i've had to replace a .find() with a context selection.

I've always thought that these were pretty interchangeable?
Why does the find not work?

```js
$(function () {
    $("#add").on("click", function() {
        $("#container").append($("#template").html());
    });
    $("#remove").on("click", function() {
        var rows = $("#container > div.row");
        var populatedRows = rows.filter(function() {
            return $(this).find("input").val();
        });
    
        if (populatedRows.length < 1) {
            rows.first().nextAll().remove();
        }
        else {
            //rows.find(populatedRows.last()).nextAll().remove();
            $(populatedRows.last(), rows).nextAll().remove();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <input />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="template" style="display:none">
  <div class="row">
    <input />
  </div>
</div>
<button id="remove" type="button">Remove</button>
<button id="add" type="button">Add</button>
```

Comment: Are you referring to `var rows = $("#container > div.row")`?

Comment: Referring to rows.find(populatedRows.last()).nextAll().remove(); VS  $(populatedRows.last(), rows).nextAll().remove();